# Add input items to Grid cells on client side then getting access to them on postback

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

HI,
I have a Telerik Grid with around 500 rows ( client requirement) and with input items it takes a while to render on browser. So in order to get around this, want to implement a system where input items are only created when the cell is edited so effectively load on demand for the input items. This works ok but problem arises when trying to access the client side input item on postback. I can't seem to get access to them, preseumably the input items aren't bound to the cell. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about using RadInputManager to boost the performance and filter the input in regular MS TextBox grid editors? I put into practice [this demo implementation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/radinputmanager/dynamicinputfiltersettings/defaultcs.aspx?product=input) and it works well for me.

Dick